# Parsing Rails HTML w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to handle the content of a bunch of divs with jQuery. It works perfectly except for the fact that when the HTML is placed inside a visible `div` it won't render elements like `<h3>` or `<br>` as HTML, they just end up being displayed as code. Any thoughts? I've tried messing around with Rails' `h(this)` or `this.html_safe`, neither of which seem to work.

This code makes the hidden 'storage' divs:

```
<div style="display: none;"><%= content_tag(:div, r.body.html_safe, :id => 'page'+i.to_s+'_hidden_article'+r.issue_id.to_s) %></div>
```

This code displays one of the above to the user:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, "", :id => "document_article#{i}_body", :class => "thumbnail") %>
```

And this is the jQuery that manages it the exchanges:

```
$('#doc_article1').change(function() {
  var src = $(this).val();
  $('#document_article1_body').text('');
  var b = $('#page1_hidden_article'+src).text();
  $('#document_article1_body').text(b);
});
```

Any help would be excellent.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `text()` with `html()` may help you solve this problem.

Comment: That was so simple! Ha. Thank-you.